# Setting scrollTop in mobile Safari doesn't include virtual keyboard

Tags: ios, mobile, safari, scrolltop, virtual-keyboard

Recently something changed to the scrollTop behavior of Mobile Safari. I want to set the scrollTop value in such a way that the bottom of the page is right above the virtual keyboard. This used to be possible and I used this feature to calculate the height of the virtual keyboard to do some smart resizing.

It seems that when the virtual keyboard is visible setting the scrollTop doesn't take into account the height of the virtual keyboard. Because of this the page is rendered behind the virtual keyboard. Offcourse it's possible to scroll further by manual input. But not using code.

A workaround for now would be to scroll to the bottom of the page by inserting a temporary input and focusing it. But I rather have a more clean solution.

Comment: 4 years later, this is still an issue. Here a blogpost which goes more into detail. (spoiler alert: it also includes the 'solution' with the 'fake input')  https://blog.opendigerati.com/the-eccentric-ways-of-ios-safari-with-the-keyboard-b5aa3f34228d